# Как отправить текстовое сообщение телеграм бот с aiogram. То есть просто что бы бот отправлял и все в чате видели (уведомления)?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Есть токен от бота и данный код, а дальше как отправить. chat_id какой должен быть что бы все в чате видели сообщение?

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
bot = Bot(token, loop, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
await bot.send_message()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C помощью этого бота определяешь ID канала `@username_to_id_bot`. Добавляешь его в беседу с полными правами, он напишет в беседу ID группы, жмешь на красный текст и вставляешь после `chat_id=''`.

Если просто копировать выделением, то не определяет знак перед числом группы и после, а они обязательно нужны - и .   .После бота можно удалить из группы.

Если вводить в чате  с ботом по определению ID ссылку на группу, то не определит, выдаст ошибку.

```py
bot.send_message(chat_id='-11111111.', text='Твой текст')
```

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек!

Comment: Рад помочь, сам недавно со всем этим мучался))